# Hibernate Unresponsive with Spring-WS

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a single-context Spring-WS application (that is, there is only one file in my project that contains  definitions), something-servlet.xml. When I call persist through my DAOs, no entries are getting created in my database. I'm also not getting any exceptions thrown.

If there is any more information I've left out that'd be helpful in determining the issue, please let me know. Thanks.

something-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.direct.mailserver" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:manager.properties" />

    <sws:annotation-driven />

    <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="manager" portTypeName="AbcDirect"
        locationUri="/mailerManagerService/" targetNamespace="http://ecsdfsds.com/direct/definitions">
        <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/mailManagerRequest.xsd" />
    </sws:dynamic-wsdl>

    <bean id="mailServerPersistenceManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="directMailDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.abc.direct.mailserver.dao"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="directMailDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Dao Classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="virtualusertable")
public class VirtualUser {

    @Id
    @Column(name="user")
    private String user;
//  private String domain;
//  private String targetAddress;

    public VirtualUser(String username) {
        this.user = username;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Component
public class VirtualUsers {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void save(VirtualUser user) {
        this.entityManager.persist(user);
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
}
```

Endpoint:

```
@Endpoint
public class MailManagerEndpoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://asfsdfs.com/direct/schemas";
    static final Namespace NAMESPACE = Namespace.getNamespace(NAMESPACE_URI);

    private MailManagerService service;
    @Autowired
    private VirtualUsers virtualUsers;

    @Autowired
    public MailManagerEndpoint(MailManagerService mailManagerService) {

        this.service = mailManagerService;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "MailManagerRequest")
    public @ResponsePayload Element handleRequest(@RequestPayload Element element) throws JDOMException, IOException {

        VirtualUser user = new VirtualUser("newuser");
        virtualUsers.save(user);

        return new Element("success");
    }
}
```

Startup logs: http://pastebin.com/9Z6MWRSG

Transaction logs: http://pastebin.com/ZFEC0EMJ

In the startup logs, I"m really curious as to why this block repeats itself like 7 times:

```
2014-04-25 10:34:03,634 DEBUG EntityLoader:146 - Static select for entity com.abc.direct.mailserver.dao.VirtualUser [READ]: select virtualuse0_.user as user1_0_0_ from virtualusertable virtualuse0_ where virtualuse0_.user=?
2014-04-25 10:34:03,635 DEBUG QuerySpacesImpl:177 - Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:0> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.EntityQuerySpaceImpl@e58a68d]
2014-04-25 10:34:03,635 DEBUG FetchStyleLoadPlanBuildingAssociationVisitationStrategy:94 - Building LoadPlan...
2014-04-25 10:34:03,635 DEBUG LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor:111 - processing queryspace <gen:0>
2014-04-25 10:34:03,636 DEBUG LoadPlanTreePrinter:72 - LoadPlan(entity=com.abc.direct.mailserver.dao.VirtualUser)
    - Returns
       - EntityReturnImpl(entity=com.abc.direct.mailserver.dao.VirtualUser, querySpaceUid=<gen:0>, path=com.abc.direct.mailserver.dao.VirtualUser)
    - QuerySpaces
       - EntityQuerySpaceImpl(uid=<gen:0>, entity=com.abc.direct.mailserver.dao.VirtualUser)
          - SQL table alias mapping - virtualuse0_
          - alias suffix - 0_
          - suffixed key columns - {user1_0_0_}
```

**UPDATE:**
persist() output after adding @Transactional and :

```
2014-04-25 11:24:47,517 DEBUG SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler:253 - Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
2014-04-25 11:24:47,950 DEBUG AbstractSaveEventListener:130 - Generated identifier: newuser, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.Assigned
2014-04-25 11:24:48,011 DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils:435 - Closing JPA EntityManager
```

Comment: Did this ever work for you? If not, this could be a @Transaction or transaction issue, try wrapping your service methods(virtualUsers) with transactional and  check.

Comment: didn't work :-\; no this hasn't been working yet. it's new

Comment: Try adding `<tx:annotation-driven/>` to your something-servlet.xml and put `@Transactional` on the `save` method of your dao class

Comment: still nothing. update with the output that i get when persist gets called with your suggestion applied

Comment: actually, your solution worked after i added a couple more things. thanks.

Comment: best answer still open to anyone who wants to provide a nice, informative answer before I do.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert data to DB, you need a transaction. In order for Spring to provide a transaction, you need to put `<tx:annotation-driven />` to your Spring context file, and put `@Transactional` annotation on the method that you insert data to DB. This way, Spring initiates a transaction for you as the method execution starts, and commits it when the method execution comes to an end (or rolls it back if an exception is thrown).